# First click not working in Show hide section in WordPress Elementor on a button/text click

Tags: javascript, elementor

I am hiding a form through button click and javascript. It works fine, but I have a problem on the first click.

When I get to the page, if I make the first click on the button, it doesn't work, but when I click on the second one, it starts working with just one click hide / view.

If I refresh the page, the first click doesn't work again.

```
<button class="myclass" onclick="myFunction()">
<style>my style</style>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    let x = document.getElementById("noform");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: check what x.style.display is on first load. Perhaps its not "none"

Comment: @dalcam Thanks for the answer, but I'm not a developer, I got the code on the net. kindly explain to me what you mean and how to do the check you suggested? Thank you

Comment: ok, im solved whit code:

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        let element = document.getElementById("noform");
        element.classList.toggle("yesform")
    }
</script>